# Remix useFetcher data is undefined ONLY on the first load()

Tags: fetch, undefined, remix, remix.run

I'm trying to use `useFetcher()` from `@remix-run/react` to fetch data from the client side when the client clicks a button. However, `fetcher.data` is set to `undefined` but only on the first `load()`.

my `app/routes/api.test.tsx`:

```js
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
    return {
        data: "test"
    };
};
```

my `app/routes/_index.tsx/`:

```js
export default function Index() {

    const testFetcher = useFetcher();


    const handleClick = () => {
        testFetcher.load("/api/test");
        console.log(testFetcher);
    };

    return (
        <div >
            <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and my `console` after two clicks of the button:
[image]

I first thought it was because `fetcher.load()` is asynchronous and the fetching wasn't done yet, but adding async/await didn't work because it wasn't an asynchronous function after all. What am I doing wrong?